# Can we share iis log folder and access that folder using log parser or db jobs?

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller, webapi

We have 20 websites hosted two servers and we would like to parse iis log files using db job. We want to keep job at centralized location and read log files from different server. To do so we need to shared iis log files folders.

Will is cause any problem to IIS web server , Since it is accessing shared files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could access iis log from another server but it should be in the same network. share that folder and assign permission to the trusted user whom you want to share the log file.
there is no issue with iis while sharing iis log to the remote server.

you could use a log parser tool. below is a script to combine iis log:

```
 logparser -i:iisw3c "select * into c:\temp\DefaultWebSite1.log from \\web1\C$\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc1\u_ex100601.log,\\web2\C$\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc1\u_ex100601.log" -o:w3c
```